# unable to display image name in script output

Tags: php

Hi I'm very new to php but I have been trying to modify some code and have hit a dead end.

I am trying to display the last 20 images uploaded to a folder, along with the file name. I have got it to the point where the images are displayed but i am unable to remove the path from the name, any help would be apprciated.

the script is shown below

```
<?php

$files = (glob('../YoungsMotors/clientimages/*.*', GLOB_BRACE)); /* change php to the file you require either html php jpg png. */
$selection = $files;

$files = array();

foreach ($selection as $file) {

    $files[$file] = 0-filemtime($file);   
}


$string = '$file';

$name = preg_replace('/../YoungsMotors/clientimages/ (.*) /','',$string);

asort($files);

foreach ($files as $file => $time) {
    $i++;
    if ($i <= 20) { /* change this to display the amount of results 1 for most recent or 10 for the 10 most recent. */
            print $image ."<br />";
echo '<img src="'.$file .'"width="200""  />'."<br />$name<br />";

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this.

```
$name = pathinfo('/var/www/html/image.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME)
```

Here is a link to the documentations : http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Regards,